# Evaluating spread sheets from nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, spreadsheet

I'm working on a project that requires a series of calculations involving specialists in different fields all with there own nomenclature and methodology. These calculations can change over time. In particular any changes based in law and calculating taxes are subject to frequent change.

These specialists don't know how to code but do build spreadsheets on a regular basis.

In order to avoid having to become a specialist in each field myself It would be a great time saver if I could load spreadsheets into my `node js` `javascript` code and evaluate them.

Something like this:

```js
const file = module.loadSpreadsheetFile('file.spreadsheet')
const mysheet = file.sheet('mysheet')
const output = mysheet.evaluate(input)
```

Where `input` would look something like:

```js
const input = {
  cellname1 = 10,
  cellname2 = 20,
  ...
}
```

Modules I have found so far only allow you to read and write from spreadsheets. Is anyone aware of a way to actually evaluate spread sheets and do calculations from nodejs?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this feature exists but maybe you don't need it. You could evaluate these calculations inside the sheet itself, put the results in certain cells and use any module that you've already found to just read the results from those cells.

Comment: How would that work? I need to set both the input values and then calculate and retrieve the output values.

Comment: You could read the excel file, set the input values in the correct cells, save the file, and re-read them but now look for the cells containing the results.
If you are using Google Sheet, you could in theory use `.setValue` and `.getValue` inside Google Scripts to do something similar. You can also set formulas there with `.setFormula`.